# Name for second last note before resolution?

Tags: cadence

If I have a phrase and there is no chords, just single tones.

The phrase ends on the tonic.

Is there a term for the second last note if its always +/- 1 step (in the scale) away from tonic?

Can I call it a type of cadence for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, the notes a half step above or below the tonic are "leading tones". However, a whole step above or below does not have a special name in terms of cadence function.

Within a scale, the half or whole steps above or below the tonic are called the supertonic and subtonic, respectively, but that term doesn't specifically describe a cadence function the way "leading tone" does.

Comment: I meant steps within the scale, not seminotes/wholenotes. So if its a whole note away from the tonic, there is no name for it?

Comment: @Invariant Nothing to specifically describe its cadential function.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about either 7>1 or 2>1, I think.

Both the 7 and the 2 are part of V, so V>I *could* be considered, making a perfect cadence (in U.K.!). However, cadences needs some form of harmony to be called cadences - hence V>I. A single note will not evoke any particular harmony, although may hint at it, especially with a build up of other 'matching' notes prior. Bt that's not enough.

There are no words to describe what you ask about, involving diatonic, or chromatic notes. A faint possibility *may* be ♭2>1, maybe calling that tts, but you specifically ask about diatonics.

**Leading note** is the term used for note 7 (*leading tone* in U.S.) but although it's always one step from the tonic in scales, that's not enough. Likewise, *supertonic* is one step from the tonic in scales, but only sometimes in pieces, so that's not enough either.

Comment: Excellent answer, although more fleshed out than the other, I will mark the other since it basically says the same, but was first.